# I have an issue with a JLabel and the BorderLayout of a JPanel

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jlabel, border-layout

I was working on this drawing program project, (more like, extending it) and I came upon a nasty bug. I added a JLabel on a JPanel, on the South of the BorderLayout, but not only it does not get added into the south of the JPanel, it also gets blurry after I paint something on the JPanel. What I do not understand is why these two things are happening.

Code of the Class:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionAdapter;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Painter extends JPanel{

private int pointCount = 0; // count the number of points

// array of 10000 java.awt.Point references
private Point[] points = new Point[10000];
JLabel myCount = new JLabel();

// set up GUI and register mouse event handler
public Painter() {

    myCount.setText("Points so far: " + pointCount);
    add(myCount, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    // handle frame mouse motion event
    addMouseMotionListener(
            new MouseMotionAdapter() { // anonymous inner class
                public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent event) {
                    if (pointCount < points.length) {
                        points[pointCount] = event.getPoint(); // find the point
                        ++pointCount; // increment number of points in the array
                        repaint();
                        myCount.setText("Points so far: " + pointCount);
                    } // end if     
            } // end of mouseDragged method
        } // end anonymous inner class
    ); // end of addMouseMotionListener
}// end Painter constructor

// draw ovals in a 4-by-4 bounding box at specified locations on window
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponents(g); // clears drawing area

    // draw all points in the array
    for (int i = 0; i < pointCount; i++) {
        g.fillOval(points[i].x, points[i].y, 12, 12);
    } // end for loop
} // end method paintComponent
} // end of Painter class
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First problem can be solved by calling setLayout(new BorderLayout); as the first line of your constructor

2nd problem can be solved by removing the 's' from paintComponents and just calling paintComponent

Comment: *"removing the 's' from paintComponents"*  Well spotted.

Comment: Thank you good sir. Just one more question. Isn't the JPanel supposed to have the BorderLayout by default?

Comment: @NlightNfotis what makes you think that? The docs don't say anything about default layout

Comment: @ControlAltDel This is over a month old, but I'll point out that "Because content panes use the `BorderLayout` class by default, the code does not need to set the layout manager." http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/border.html